# How do I set margin between label and input on only 3 inputs on a HTML form?

Tags: html, css, forms

I set my labels to have a margin of 10 em but I want 3 of my labels to not be included in this change. How will I make sure that those do not get included. I have the 3 that I do not want changed in a div element with an id of "name" in the html file but I am not sure how to specify those 3 in the css file so that it will not get included in the margin change for the labels. I am only familiar with using the types to distinguish. For example:

```
input:not[type="text"]{
margin:10em }
```

But I want to be able to use the id of the div or the inputs instead of the type. Is this possible. I am open to different ways as well

current CSS file:

```
label{
    width:10em;
    /*margin:auto auto 1em auto;*/
    display:inline-block;
}

input{
    margin:auto 5em auto auto;

}







  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content= "width=device-width initial=scale=1" name="viewport">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sign Ups!</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" id="registration" name="registration">
            
        <div class="name">
                <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
                <input name="FirstName" id="FirstName" type="text" required>
             
                <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
                <input name="LastName" id="LastName" type="text" required>
    
                <label for="MiddleName">M</label>
                <input name="MiddleName" id="MiddleName" type="text"><br><br>
            </div>
                <label for="Email">Email</label>
                <input name="Email" id="Email" type="email" required><br><br>
    
                <label for="Mailing Address">Mailing Address</label>
                <input name="Mailing Address" id="Mailing Address" type="text" required><br><br>
    
                <label for="City">City</label>
                <input name="City" id="City" type="text"><br><br>
    
                <label for="Postal Code">Postal Code</label>
                <input name="Postal Code" id="Postal Code" type="text"><br><br>
    
                <label for="Date of Birth">Date of Birth</label>
                <input name="DOB" id="Date of Birth" type="date"><br><br>
    
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Gender?</legend>
                <label for="male">Male</label><input name="gender" id="male" type="radio" required><br><br>
                <label for="female">Female</label><input name="gender" id="female" type="radio" required><br><br>
                </fieldset>
    
                <label for="Phone">Phone</label>
                <input name="Phone" id="Phone" required type="phone"><br><br>
    
                
                <label for = "outreach">How did you hear about us?</label>
                <select name="Outreach" id="Outreach">How did you hear about us?
                    <option value = "walk-in">Walk-in</option>
                    <option value = "facebook">Facebook</option>
                    <option value = "referral">Referral</option>
                    <option value = "email">Email</option>
                    <option value = "signs">Ground Signs</option>
                </select>

            <input type = "submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the html

Comment: Yep. I just posted the HTML above

Answer (score 0):

So first change their id="name" to class="name".
and then

```
div .name{  
margin: none;
}
```

or you can set margin to whatever u want.
(id) only specifies one tag  u cant use it for 3 label tags
you must use class for them.

Comment: I'll try this today and let you know. Thank You

Comment: i thought this would work but unfortunately it didn't change anything. I just posted the html above

Comment: What I want to accomplish is to decrease the space between the labels of the three and their input fields. I am thinking I am going to have to change the padding of the label. Not sure though.

Comment: remember to use  box-sizing: border-box;

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-child for this

```
div .name:nth-child(1){
  margin: 10em;
}
```

The nth-child(1) is the first label that contains the name class. If you put their nth-child(2) then will work on the second label which contains the name class. Like that you can increase the number according to how many elements you have.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for this

`input:read-only` - Selects input elements with the "readonly" attribute specified

**For Example**

```css
input:read-only {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h3>A demonstration of the :read-only selector.</h3>

<p>A normal input element:<br><input value="hello"></p>

<p>A readonly input element:<br><input readonly value="hello"></p>

<p>The :read-only selector selects form elements with a "readonly" attribute.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Do tell me if I resolved your problem :)